# HTML5 video, poster img doesnt show in IE

Tags: css, html, video

I've got a small problem - I have a HTML5 video om my site, it works fine in FF, Chrome, Safari. However, it only shows the video in IE if I set autoplay="autoplay". Somehow it doesn't show the poster img - You can see it here, http://test.jsworldmedia.com/ Just press See Video. Anyone know what is wrong?

The code is:

```xml
<video id="videoContainer" width="932" height="524" controls="controls" poster="/media/13037/big_buck_bunny_poster.jpg">
    <source src="http://test.jsworldmedia.com/media/13010/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://test.jsworldmedia.com/media/13555/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="http://test.jsworldmedia.com/media/13034/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <object id="flash_fallback_1" class="vjs-flash-fallback" width="932" height="524" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="config={'playlist':['http://test.jsworldmedia.com/media/13037/big_buck_bunny_poster.jpg', {'url': 'http://test.jsworldmedia.com/media/13010/big_buck_bunny.mp4','autoPlay':false,'autoBuffering':true}]}" />
            <img src="http://test.jsworldmedia.com/media/13037/big_buck_bunny_poster.jpg" width="932" height="542" alt="" title="No video playback capabilities." />
    </object>
</video>
```

Comment: I found a solution with jQuery

    $("#fancyvideo").click(function () {
        $('video')[0].play();
        return false;
    });

Answer (score 11):

IE9 overwrites the poster image if some of the video is loaded, which is the default. If you add the attribute `preload="none"` the poster image will work in IE9.

Not ideal.

**edit**
I've [written about this](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2011/12/html5/the-problem-with-the-poster-attribute) and have also filed a [bug report](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=15140) with the W3C as I think that it needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the `poster` attribute to be too inconsistent.  For me, `preload="none"` only fixed the IE 9 problem.

**You are better off editing your video so that the poster image is the first frame of your video.**

I am a big fan of this [Video for Everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody) site which outlines exactly how one should implement the html5 `<video>` tag with fallbacks.  The author talks specifically about the `poster` attribute, mentioning inconsistent support and a major bug in iOS 3.x as reasons to encode the poster image into the first frame of your video.

You can also check out [VideoJs](http://videojs.com/) which will handle many of the cross browser issues.

**EDIT (2012-11-04):** VideoJs may not be a good option, major issues reported with IE 9.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I did the following to have the poster working in IE8 and IE9.

In html file add an image bellow the video element with the poster as src:

```
<img id="video-poster" width="460px" height="260px" src="img/video_poster.jpg">
```

In css file add:

```
#video-poster {position: absolute; z-index: 600; display: none;}`
```

Note that the parent need to have in css `position: relative`

In JS file add:

```
/**
 * fix the following issue: "video preview not showing properly on IE8 and IE9"
 */
(function ($) {
    var browserIEInfo = navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE (([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?)/);
    if (browserIEInfo === null || parseInt(browserIEInfo[2]) > 9){
        return;
    }

    if (parseInt(browserIEInfo[2]) < 9 && !isFlashSupported()) {
        return;
    }

    var video = $('video'); // use element id if there is more than 1 video
    var videoPoster = $('#video-poster');

    $( window ).resize(function() {
        fixVideoCoverPosition();
    });

    fixVideoCoverPosition();
    videoPoster.show();

    videoPoster.click(function() {
        video.get(0).play()
    });

    video.on('playing', function() {
        videoPoster.hide();
    });

    video.on('ended', function() {
        videoPoster.show();
    });

    function isFlashSupported() {
        var hasFlash = false;
        try {
            new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash');
        } catch (e) {
            var mimeTypes = navigator.mimeTypes;
            if (mimeTypes
                && mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash'] !== undefined
                && mimeTypes['application/x-shockwave-flash']['enabledPlugin']
            ) {
                hasFlash = true;
            }
        }

        return hasFlash;
    }

    function fixVideoCoverPosition() {
        var videoPosition = video.position();
        video.width();
        $('#video-poster').css({
            top: videoPosition.top,
            left: videoPosition.left,
            width: video.width(),
            height: video.height()
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```