# VIDEO JS : poster image not showing in Flash fallback on IE8

Tags: video.js

I've run into a slight problem with the new videojs. It all works fine except for the fallback image in Flash.
Here is the example : http://www.360-webdesign.fr/preprod/seasonsgreetings2012/
Note : I've deliberatly made it fallback on Flash whatever the browser or the version you are using.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please see how I handle this issue in http://stackoverflow.com/a/22169983/1263890

Comment: Better late than never. Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed your page sourcecode back to your photo and got nothing. This means the file name is incorrect. Check for mispellings and typos.

Your poster
The photo should be here

http://360-webdesign.fr/img/chaumet.jpg

Here is a photo from your main site which appears by linking it in the same manner.

http://360-webdesign.fr/img/contact_label_open.png

The poster image is not appearing because the file being called for is incorrect.

just to let you know your site does not even display text or images on my internet explorer 8 here in the states. Your page does not appear in msie 5,6,7 or 8. msie 9 displays fine

To check how your image appears broadly you can go to 
browsershots.org

Answer (score 0):

http://browsershots.org

360-webdesign.fr/--- not appearing in msie 5,6,7,8. works in msie9

screenshot from browsershots

http://s1300.beta.photobucket.com/user/aberrated/media/360webdesignnotappearinginmsei556070806_zps7f8a9385.jpg.html